# implement abstract method without calling it directly

Tags: java, abstract-class

I have an abstract class

```
public abstract class Sender {

    private IThrottler throttler;

    public final Object sendMessage(String smsText, String smsSenderName, String contactNumber) throws Exception {
        tdLogger.info("sending request >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
        String messageId = (String) sendSMS(smsText, smsSenderName, contactNumber);
        tdLogger.info("request sent    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");

        return messageId;
    }

    public final Object throttleMessage(String smsText, String smsSenderName, String contactNumber) throws Exception {
        if (throttler != null) {
            throttler.acquire();
            tdLogger.info("sending request >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
            String messageId = (String) sendSMS(smsText, smsSenderName, contactNumber);
            tdLogger.info("request sent    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
            return messageId;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("throttler is not initialized");
        }
    }

    public abstract Object send(String smsText, String smsSenderName, String contactNumber) throws Exception;

}
```

I have another class `SenderImpl`  that which extends `Sender`

is there a way to force implementing the function `send` without giving the ability to call it directly and only be able to call `sendMessage` and `throttleMessage` to force running certain logic?

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: @ScaryWombat, the implementation, but I can't find a way to disable calling the implemented directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the abstract send method `protected` so that only subclasses and classes in the same package can call it. This achieves what you intend even if it can be circumvented by placing a class in the same package.